# How to Input 2 vectors in C++ of String Data Type and Copare them and Replace Some Elements Respectively

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, cin

1. I am trying to create a list/vector of censored words of string data type.
2. There is another string vector containing a list of words.
3. Both the vectors use user input, "cin>>" to input the list of words.
4. When I run my program, I want to input buffer to exit after the first vector is entered. And Take the input from the second vector.
5. Then I want to compare the vectors and replace certain words.

Problem: When I press Ctrl + D to exit the 1st {1.} input stream, the program ends. It doesn't take the second vector input. Is there a way to put a "key-value" which can be used to exit the input streams.

```
//BLEEPING CENSORED WORDS

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<string>words;
    vector<string>words_disliked;
    
    cout << "Enter the list censored Words : " << endl;
    for (string input1; cin >> input1;) {
        words_disliked.push_back(input1);
    }


    cout << "\n\n\n\n";
    cout << "Enter the word list : " << endl;
    //WE CANT READ A VECTOR USING cin >> for now
    for (string input2; cin >> input2;) {
        words.push_back(input2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < words_disliked.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (words[i] == words_disliked[j])
                cout << " Bleep ";
            else
                cout << " " << words[i] << " " << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: 1) Ask how many censored words there are, or 2) Have them enter a sentinel word (like "END") to determine the end of the list.  There is no need to overengineer simple input.

Comment: Ok so, are you suggesting that I ask the user for an input about numbers of censored words to use it a delimiter to end the vector input? 
Can you give me an example how to use a sentinel word like “END” to define as end of list. Do I use a simple while loop? Or is there any function from the Standard Library that I can use? 

I am new to C++ so I am unfamiliar with STL. 
Thank you for your comment.

Comment: `if (input1 == "END") break;` instead of adding it to the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Ctrl+D` to end the input, simply have a sentinel word such as `"END"` to determine the end of the input:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words_disliked, words;
    //... 
    std::cout << "Enter the list censored Words (or END to stop the input): " << std::endl;
    std::string input1;
    while (true)
    {
       std::cin >> input1;
       if (input1 == "END")
          break; 
       words_disliked.push_back(input1);
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n\nEnter the word list  (or END to stop the input): " << std::endl;
    while (true)
    {
       std::cin >> input1;
       if (input1 == "END")
          break; 
       words.push_back(input1);
    }
    
    std::cout << "Here are the bad words:\n";
    for (auto& w : words_disliked)
       std::cout << w << "\n";
       
    std::cout << "\n\nHere is the word list:\n";
    for (auto& w : words)
       std::cout << w << "\n";
}
```

Input:

```
ABC DEF GHI END JOE TOM BOB JACK JILL END
```

Output:

```
Here are the bad words:
ABC
DEF
GHI


Here is the word list:
JOE
TOM
BOB
JACK
JILL
```